# clang: error: no such file or directory:

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, compiler-construction

I'm trying to compile a project using OAuth2Client, I get the error:

```
Ld /Users/willmoss26/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Elance5WS-ebjkwadamxzcifcdxvdmtiiqdpoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ELance5.app/ELance5 normal i386
cd /Users/willmoss26/Documents/XCode/ELance5
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/willmoss26/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Elance5WS-ebjkwadamxzcifcdxvdmtiiqdpoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/willmoss26/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Elance5WS-ebjkwadamxzcifcdxvdmtiiqdpoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/willmoss26/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Elance5WS-ebjkwadamxzcifcdxvdmtiiqdpoy/Build/Intermediates/ELance5.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ELance5.build/Objects-normal/i386/ELance5.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 /Users/willmoss26/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Elance5WS-ebjkwadamxzcifcdxvdmtiiqdpoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OAuth2Client/OAuth2Client -lOAuth2Client -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/willmoss26/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Elance5WS-ebjkwadamxzcifcdxvdmtiiqdpoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ELance5.app/ELance5

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/willmoss26/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Elance5WS-ebjkwadamxzcifcdxvdmtiiqdpoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OAuth2Client/OAuth2Client'
```

How can I solve that?

I've already

- checked User Header Search Path to include the libary
- ensured Base SDK & compile settings are for iOS6 / armv7
- added .framework & .a files from project to Linked Frameworks & Libraries

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked whether `/Users/willmoss26/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Elance5WS-   ebjkwadamxzcifcdxvdmtiiqdpoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OAuth2Client/OAuth2Client` really means `/Users/willmoss26/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Elance5WS-ebjkwadamxzcifcdxvdmtiiqdpoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OAuth2Client/OAuth2Client`

Comment: Well this directory definitely doesn't exist..... maybe its just temporarily created by the compiler for some reason?

Comment: Its seem like a pretty random directory, it's certainly not in my current working directory.

Answer (score 8):

Go to your Target ->Build settings ->other linker flag and see if this is done or not =>
-framework
Foundation

Answer (score 1):

Go to Build Phase page of your project and expand Compile Sources to remove those files which are  highlighted with red color.

Comment: Can you expand this to explain how and why this will help?